# Securing user's credentials in flask application that doesn't use a database, but rather is web scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am creating a web application for students at my university. They will input their email and password of their university credentials, and my application will take their password, log in the university website for them, and scrape some data that will be presented in a much better way.

These are my questions:

1. What is the most secure way to use their credentials, make sure that the password is always secured and hashed, and deleted from the server as soon as the program can log in using their credentials?
2. In what way should I be treating their credentials in a secure manner? I am not using my flask application with a database, I am using their credentials to log in someplace else and scrape some data.

Below are the files for how I am currently doing it. I am aware it is extremely not secure.

So after the user log's in to my application, the routes.py file shows how I am accepting a POST request for the scraper tool, and writing it into a separate file containing a global variable for the students username and password.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import request
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for, request, jsonify
import settings
import json


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
 return render_template('landing.html')

@app.route('/webScraperTool', methods =['POST'])
def webScraperTool():
 settings.email = request.form['email'];
 settings.password = request.form['password'];

 import UniversitySiteScraperTool
 return jsonify(settings.jsonObjects)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The settings file contains the global variable for the credentials.

```
global email
email = ""
global password
password = ""
```

And finally my UniversitySiteScraperTool will use the global variables and use a chrome driver to automate logging in.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import re
import numpy as np
import datetime
import sys
import settings
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

################# DRIVER CODE PORTION #################
# Executable path ->

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=settings.dirpath + '/chromedriver')
    #Url to DWORKS
url = "University Website URL"
driver.get(url)


##username and password##
usernameStr = settings.email
passwordStr = settings.password

username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)

password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
password.send_keys(passwordStr)

nextButton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#welcome > div > div.row.btn-row > input.btn-submit')
#After I fill in their credentials, click the submit button
nextButton.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just scraping a site that takes the username and password in plain-text, there isn't really a good manner for you to store the users' passwords securely while still making them recoverable so you can scrape the site.

Having said that, you aren't really "writing to a separate file", like you state, but rather the username and password are just being held in memory, even though those variables are contained in a different file.

For that reason, I would think it would just be simpler for you to have your scraper tool be a class that receives the username and password upon instantiation. Then when it is complete and the object is destroyed the username and password are destroyed with it.

Basically, the structure would look largely like what you have, but wrapped in a class:

```
class Scraper(object):
    __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=settings.dirpath + '/chromedriver')

    scrape_site(self):
        url = "University Website URL"
        driver.get(url)

        username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
        username.send_keys(self.username)

        password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
        password.send_keys(self.password)

        nextButton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#welcome > div > div.row.btn-row > input.btn-submit')
        nextButton.click()
```

Then you can use this code in your main app as follows:

```
from UniversitySiteScraperTool import Scraper
Scraper(request.form['email'], request.form['password']).scrape_site()
```